# how to create oData service for rest api in node js

Tags: node.js, rest, powerbi, odata, elastic-stack

i am new to odata
i want to know how to create odata service for rest api in my node js

i want to integrate power bi

i searched about odata but found very old documentation

found few packages but they also dont have proper documentation

https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-odata-server

https://github.com/htammen/n-odata-server

`"n-odata-server": { "path": "/odata/*", "odataversion": "2", "useViaMiddleware": true }`